# Regarding left shift operator in C++

Tags: c++, shift

I have this doubt regarding left shift operator, when I perform-

```
int n=(1<<1);
cout<<n;
```

**Output: 2**

```
int n=(1<<(1<<1));
cout<<n;
```

**Output: 4**

But when, I do-

```
int n=(1<<(1<<(1<<1));
cout<<n;
```

**Output: 16**

Shouldn't the output be 8 in the last case? Why it is giving 16?

Comment: Have you tried to evaluate it manually according to the parentheses precedence rule?

Comment: Why did you expect it give 8?

Comment: @MartinBonner I think the expectation was shifting one more time, instead of having it raised to the power of something.

Answer (score 8):

```
int n=(1<<(1<<(1<<1));
=> int n=(1<<(1<<2));
=> int n=(1<<4); // which is to say, 2 to the power of 4
=> 1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 8 -> 16
```

So it should display 16.

Answer (score 5):

Since `1 << n = 2^n` it is easy to evaluate:

```
(1<<(1<<(1<<1)) = 2^(2^(2^1)) = 2^4 = 16
```

- Here `x^y` denotes `x` raised to the power of `y`, and not the `C++` XOR operator.

Comment: How will you evaluate (4<<16) ?

Comment: `x << y = x * (2^y)`

Answer (score 2):

This is a basic case of operator precedence. The innermost parentheses will be evaluated first, and this will chain up to the outermost one. So, for the last case, it will go

```
(1<<(1<<(1<<1))) => (1<<(1<<2)) => (1<<4) = 16
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you grouped it backwards:

If you do:

```
int n=(((1<<1)<<1)<<1);
cout<<n;
```

Output will be `(((1<<1)<<1)<<1) = (((2)<<1)<<1) = ((4)<<1) = 8`

Remember that left operand of shift operator `<<` is the number you want to apply the shift, and the right operand is the `n` bits you want to shift.

So, if you group it backwards, you are shifting the rigth operand (the `n` bits you want to shift).

```
int n=(1<<(1<<(1<<1)));
cout<<n;
```

Output will be `(1<<(1<<(1<<1))) = (1<<(1<<(2))) = (1<<(4)) = 16`

Answer (score 1):

Every time you shift to the left, you are incrementing the number to the power of 2.

The first expression `(1<<1)` was `2^1` which is `2`.
The second expression `(1<<(1<<1))` was `( 1<< (2) )` which is `2^2` or `4`

The last expression `(1<<(1<<(1<<1)))` was just `(1<<(4))` which is `4^2` or `16`.

Answer (score 0):

The decimal number 1 in binary is : 1 ; 2^0

when you shift it to the left it becomes : 10 ; (1<<1)

The next executed operation would be 1<<2 which results in : 100 = 4 ; (1<<2)

And the one after that : 1 << 4 which makes...you guessed it - 10000 = 16 ; (1<<4)

I hope this helped somebody.